# Safari CSS3 transform height limit

Tags: javascript, html, safari, css

I have a viewport div (`testframe`), which contains a bunch of other divs within. I'm using css transforms to slide `innerFrame` within `testframe`. The code is as follows.

HTML:

```
<div id="testframe" style="height: 400px; overflow: hidden">
  <div id="innerFrame"></div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for(var i=0; i<9999; i++) {
    $('#innerFrame').append('<div style="margin: 9px; background-color: blue; height: 9999px"></div>')
  }
  $('#innerFrame').append('<div>Hi'+Math.random()+'</div>')

  useTransforms = true
  if(!useTransforms) {
    $('#innerFrame').css({
      'position': 'relative',
      'top': '-100069900px'
    })
  } else {
    $('#innerFrame')[0].style.webkitTransitionProperty = '-webkit-transform'
    $('#innerFrame')[0].style.webkitTransitionDuration = "2000ms"
    $('#innerFrame')[0].style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px,-100069900px,0)"
  }
});
```

In Safari if I use css transforms (`useTransforms = true`) then the bottom of the div isn't rendered. However if I use the elements `top` to control it, it does get rendered.

This only occurs when the height is greater than about `130000px`. Does anyone know why this happens, or a work around to fix the issue? Please note that in the full code I'm using css3 transitions for smooth scrolling on iOS/Safari so using just using the elements top isn't a solution in this scenario.

Comment: I believe, this is a "hardcoded" limit and it is 131072 pixels.

Comment: @kirilloid so is it a CSS3 transform limit because css top works fine?

Comment: Seemes to be so. Do not lose hope, though, cause I'm not sure =)

Comment: Does this occur only on iOS? Your code seems to work fine for me on Safari 5.0.3 Mac.

Comment: I'm getting this issue in Safari 5.0.3 and iOS

Comment: may be the value limitation is safari practice, as what they do in [z-index](http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add the following to the element currently in the viewport (`#testframe`)

```
$(currentElement)[0].style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
```

This seems to force the render. However use this with care, because it can cause a browser crash in iOS if used on too many elements (explained here http://cubiq.org/testing-memory-usage-on-mobile-safari)